# How to change the setting for a network device reported by ethtool, specifically Speed, on VM?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, openstack, gigabit-ethernet, ethtool

This is related to these two questions, although they don't answer my question.

The machines are RHEL6.

1.[ethtool not showing all the properties](https://serverfault.com/questions/447939/why-is-ethtool-not-showing-me-all-the-properties-for-a-nic)
2.[changing network speed to 1000Mb/s](https://serverfault.com/questions/444382/changing-network-speed-to-1000mb-s?rq=1)

Output on VM:

```
 [root@foo ~]# ethtool eth0 Settings for eth0:
       Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
         Link detected: yes
```

Output on Real Hardware: (interested in Speed)

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        ***Speed: 1000Mb/s***
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes
```

if there's anyway I can set this in VM, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be safe to assume that `ethtool -I eth0` on the virtual server will display virtio_net or similar as the driver.

That means that eth0 is a **virtual** network interface and **not a network card**. It exists purely as a kernel construct in memory and has no limitations such as fixed speed, link detection etc. It only sends and receives packets.

You could instruct the hypervisor to emulate a NIC and then you would get ethtool to show speed, duplex setting and the whole shebang in the virtual server, but at quite a performance overhead.

Comment: Do you meant `-i` instead of `-I`? The capital "I" switch doesn't seem to be implemented in newer version of ethtool. And `-i` shows the attached driver; that seems to be what you originally aimed at, correct?